# Apply labels from a stream to a Bitraversable

Tags: haskell

Labelling `Traversable` containers is an ancient and honorable test of skill. My task here is to create a **generic labelling mechanism** for a `Bitraversable`, such as a tuple, or a graph with vertex and edge labels.

```
bilabelWith
    :: Bitraversable t
    => (l ->  indexl -> l') -> (r ->  indexr -> r')
    -> Stream indexl        -> Stream indexr
    -> t l r -> t l' r'
bilabelWith f g xs ys =
  let labelLeft  = fmap (withStateLens fst (\(_, y) x' -> (x', y))) (labelOneWith f)
      labelRight = fmap (withStateLens snd (\(x, _) y' -> (x, y'))) (labelOneWith g)
  in flip evalState (xs, ys) . bitraverse labelLeft labelRight

labelOneWith :: (a -> index -> b) -> a -> State (Stream index) b
labelOneWith f u = do
    (Stream.Cons x xs) <- get
    put xs
    return (f u x)

withStateLens :: (s -> t) -> (s -> t -> s) -> State t a -> State s a
withStateLens thrust merge u = do
    s <- get
    let t = thrust s
    let (r, t') = runState u t
    put (merge s t')
    return r
```

**Here is how it may be applied:**

```
λ bilabelWith (+) (*) (Stream.fromList [2]) (Stream.fromList [3]) (5, 7)
(7,21)
```

A more complicated example requires us to obtain a `Bitraversable` graph.

```
circular :: (DynGraph gr, Bitraversable gr) => gr a b -> gr (V2 Double, a) b
circular gr =
  let n = fromIntegral (Graph.noNodes gr)
      coords =
        let alpha = (pi * 2 / n)
        in Stream.prefix [ 0.8 * V2 (sin (alpha * i)) (cos (alpha * i)) | i <- [1.. n] ]
            $ error "circular: Impossible error: not enough coordinates to label all points."
  in bilabelWith (flip (,)) const coords (Stream.repeat ()) gr
```

**Does this code make sense?** Is there anything to make more compact or clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fmap` in `labelLeft` should be `(.)`. `Control.Lens.Zoom` provides something like `withStateLens`. Inline definitions that are only used once.

```
bilabelWith
    :: Bitraversable t
    => (l ->  indexl -> l') -> (r ->  indexr -> r')
    -> Stream indexl        -> Stream indexr
    -> t l r -> t l' r'
bilabelWith f g xs ys = flip evalState (xs, ys) .
  bitraverse (zoom _1 . pops . f) (zoom _2 . pops . g)

pops :: (s -> a) -> State (Stream s) a
pops = flip fmap $ state $ \(Stream.Cons x xs) -> (x, xs)
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks nice. Can you explain the `pops` part in more detail?

Comment: `\(Stream.Cons x xs) -> (x, xs)` should be `Stream.uncons`. `state` produces simple `State` objects. `pop = state Stream.uncons` is a usual name for taking the front item off a queue. `s` is a usual suffix to add a hook of form `s -> a`, see `gets` or `uses`. `pops f = fmap f pop`.

Comment: I see. Perhaps in pointy style it would have been more readable.